# Selectize dropdown is not overlapping Parent Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, extjs, selectize.js

I am trying to create a dropdown with Jquery ,selectize and Extjs on a ExtJS panel

But when i click on the dropdown it shows half of the item inside the Panel, i need it to overlap the panel and display.

[image: Ext JS Panel]

Ext js code for this panel is this

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    renderTo: 'helloWorldPanel',
    height: 200,
    width: 600,
    title: 'Hello world',
    html: 'First Ext JS Hello World Program',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Rank',
        fieldCls : 'js-rank',
        listeners: {
            render : function () {

            },
            afterrender: function(){
                $('.js-rank').parent().removeClass("x-form-text-wrap x-form-text-wrap-default");

                $('.js-rank').removeClass("x-form-text x-form-text-default").select([{rank:'20',rankName:'20'},
                    {rank:'30',rankName:'30'},{rank:'40',rankName:'40'},
                    {rank:'50',rankName:'50'},{rank:'60',rankName:'60'},{rank:'70',rankName:'70'}]);
            }
        }
    }],

});
```

});

Inspect Element is below

[image]

Comment: you'll need to remove the overflow hidden from panel body.

Answer (score 0):

It worked when i did the following changes

```
 $(jqueryObject).parents().removeClass('x-fieldset x-fieldset-body x-panel-body');
    $(jqueryObject).removeClass("x-form-text x-form-text-default");
    $(jqueryObject).parent().removeClass("x-form-text-wrap x-form-text-wrap-default");
```

i am not sure removing those classes is the right way to do that